# URL for web hosting

Tags: html, url-rewriting, hosting

The person I use for hosting my website has told me that my website will look like this in the browser.

```
http://www.website.domain/folder/index.html
```

I would prefer the site to look like this:

```
A - http://www.website.domain/
```

or

```
B - http://www.website.domain/index.html
```

I am almost certain this is possible, and they just do not know how to set some kind of file path.  This is a one page html site and the entire site is contained within 1 folder.  So I have decided to go and find a company that will host my site (i.e. 1and1.com).

First, how do I set up web hosting for either of my preferred ways?  What is the preference among web developers on preference A or B?

Second, what would be the consequences of adding a second folder containing another website.  Would the second website still be able to have a URL of style A or B without interfering with the first website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure your web server's document root for each vhost accordingly.  If your web host won't do this for you, or doesn't let you do it... find a new web host.

Comment: -1 'eh?  Got a reason to add to the discussion?  Or are you the type that likes wasting your time?

Comment: thanks @Brad, btw I didn't dvote ya... sorry

Comment: @Justin, No worries, it's quite the common occurrence on StackOverflow.  I have no issues with the folks that downvote things and explain themselves, for everyone's benefit.  I do find it amusing when people downvote correct answers with no explanation.

Comment: Is there a preference between the two styles of urls displayed in the address bar?

Comment: @Justin, It is a matter of preference, but for some SEO benefit, your URL should align with the content on the page.  `index.html` doesn't say anything about the content, and since it is generally a default document anyway, I recommend leaving it off.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good tool called **mod_rewrite** for that.

Getting started: http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls

Complex examples:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: Doubtful I can use this, as I am not sure what the web server would be from the web hosting company.